# Connect to Visual Studio server from remote machine using Fiddler and HTTPS

Tags: visual-studio, ssl, https, visual-studio-2013, fiddler

I am trying to connect to a Visual Studio server from a remote machine using Fiddler and HTTPS. I followed this tutorial (http://docs.telerik.com/fiddler/Configure-Fiddler/Tasks/UseFiddlerAsReverseProxy) which works perfectly for HTTP. When I moved my project to HTTPS, the connection stopped working. I have tried several solutions, including:

- [Proxying HTTPS traffic through Fiddler fails for remote clients?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15841101/proxying-https-traffic-through-fiddler-fails-for-remote-clients)
- http://lifelongprogrammer.blogspot.com.au/2014/04/using-fiddler-as-https-reverse-proxy.html

but haven't been able to get it to work. Can someone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You haven't explained what happens, but my guess is that your client is trying to do a HTTPS handshake with Fiddler, which is expecting HTTP because you didn't tell it to do anything else.

In Fiddler's QuickExec box, type

`!listen 444 FiddlerMachineName`

This will create a new HTTPS-accepting endpoint running at `https://FiddlerMachineName:444` and Fiddler will perform a HTTPS handshake on all inbound connections. You can then use FiddlerScript to forward requests to the target service.

Comment: Thanks, this has certainly resolved my HTTPS issue. However, I continue to have an issue with my hostname, which means I am unable to connect from a remote machine. I have created a new question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396126/hostname-not-resolving-to-local-ip-address

Comment: @noilly: Curious. In Fiddler, if you hover over the "Online" badge at the top-right of the toolbar, do you see more than one IP address listed?

Comment: no I only see one. I worked out that the strange IP address  is the response created by the Mac when it can't resolve a hostname - very weird. So I think I will take a different strategy regarding the VM's IP - maybe you can answer thew question I've posed here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25402478/in-fiddlerscript-is-there-a-way-to-access-the-current-machines-local-ip