# Hostname not resolving to local IP address

Tags: networking, ip, vmware, host, hostname

I am running a Windows 8 VM inside of vmware Fusion. It runs inside a Mac running OSX 10.10 (Yosemite). The VM has a computer name of "Proud". When I ping the VM from within itself, i.e. `ping -a 192.168.0.138` I get a response like:

`Pinging Proud [192.168.0.138] with 32 bytes of data:
 Reply from 192.168.0.138: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128`

However whenever I ping Proud from Yosemite, i.e. `ping Proud` I get a response like:

`PING proud (199.101.28.130): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 199.101.28.130: icmp_seq=0 ttl=46 time=418.646 ms`

The VM is using bridged networking.

Why does Proud resolve to that IP address? It is not correct and means I am unable to use the hostname (a necessity) so that I can connect to it from the Mac.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems to be a 'feature' of Mac OS. If I attempt to ping any hostname it will return the ping from this IP address - even if the hostname is fictional. I do not know why OS X does this.

Comment: As has been said at the very begining, to **isolate the root cause of the objected issue**, there was a manual **ping** to be done in Step #1. Those results than influence the ARP resolution and the higher layers, incl. the DNS name-resolving steps. Neither the Step #1 **ping**, nor the OSX **ifconfig** or the w8 **ipconfig** screenshots were done/posted. Pitty.

Comment: @user3666197 I commented on your answer as I didn't understand your instructions, but no response was provided.

Comment: With all due respect, what did prevent you from typing **ping 192.168.0.138** on OSX-terminal window on [Yosemite] and then posting a printscreen with a text output  here? The same for **ifconfig** command output and so forth...? Nevertheless, enjoy the weekend :o)

Answer (score 0):

**First**, test and check  with **`IP_address`** typed for `ping` from OSX 10.10 <*host*> terminal, so as to be independent of any DNS-service, that is responsible for a **`hostname`** translation of your <*hostname*> to a pre-configured IP_adress

**Second**, You say bridged -- thus check, that the VM has the very same ***network-part*** of the **`IP_address`** ( boundary is given by non-zero bits in **`subnet-mask`**

Check details with **`ifconfig`** resp. **`ipconfig`**

```
-------------------------|-----------------------------|||--------|||.|||.|||.|||
VM/w8  connected to VMnet? has IP_address := 192.168.0.??? subnet ???.???.???.???
RM/OSX connected to VMnet? has IP_address := 192.168.0.??? subnet ???.???.???.???
```

**`EDIT#1`**`2014-08-20 15:30 [UTC+0000]:`

```
-------------------------?-----------------------------???--------255.255.255.0
-------------------------|-----------------------------|||
```

Best to post PrintScreens from {OSX|w8} terminals {ping|ipconfig|ifconfig} and the setup of VMnet

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand your instructions. Could you be explicit?

Comment: For the second point, they both have the same network portion (192.168.0.x) and subnet masks (255.255.255.0).

Answer (score 0):

This is called DNS hijacking and is done by a lot of ISPs out there to redirect you on incomplete or wrong browser address inputs and show you these custom pages with advertisment 'Hey, we couldn't find your webpage Aple.com but maybe you look for Apple.com?'

Maybe this is whats happening here. Btw, ISPs break RFCs here.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check on your own /etc/host file. See if you might have done any changes to this file, to indicate the machine "Proud" comes as 192.168.0.138 or x.x.x.130? Next thing to ensure (user3666197 is actually right), you need to check on ifconfig to check if you have any connection have the IP address pointing to x.x.x.130 or x.x.x.138.

Last but not least, is there any virtual appliance or instance running of "proud" which might have caused confusion as it is possible for any virtual appliance or instance to get a IP address from the same segment as well, hence having "two" machines on the network?

Hope this helps. Check on your WINS config too...