# In FiddlerScript, is there a way to access the current machine's local IP?

Tags: fiddler

I am running a web server on a machine with a dynamic IP. I would like to be able to modify the following statement in OnBeforeRequest():

```
if (oSession.host.toLowerCase() == "192.168.0.150:444") {  
    oSession.host = "localhost:44300";
}
```

so that I don't have to hardcode the machine's IP (in this case, 192.168.0.150 - the machine on which Fiddler is running). Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have full access to the .NET Framework's API, so you can enumerate all of the current machine's IP addresses.

e.g.

```
var ipAddrs = Dns.GetHostAddresses(String.Empty);
```

You should change your comparison to use the `hostname` member:

```
if ((oSession.port == 444) && (oSession.hostname == "192.168.0.150")
```

Is there a reason that your clients are accessing this server via its IP rather than via its hostname (e.g. `http://myserver:444/`)

Comment: The machine I am attempting to access is a Windows 8 VM hosted in MAC OS X 10.10. The hostname of the VM is "Proud". Whenever I attempt `ping proud` from my Mac OS, it returns pings from a bogus IP (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25396126/hostname-not-resolving-to-local-ip-address). If I `ping proud.local` it returns the correct IP. However, if I try to access https://proud.local:444 the browser is unable to resolve the address. Accessing https://proud.local:444 from within the VM works (thanks to Fiddler).

Comment: Unfortunately, this actually hasn't truly resolved my issue as every time the dynamic IP changes on the Windows VM I have to run `!listen 444 xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' in Fiddler... which is prohibitive.

Comment: Your comment about the `listen` command doesn't really make sense in relation to the question you've asked here.

Comment: Your solution definitely answers my question, and I had hoped it would help solve a greater problem. The reason why I needed this answer was because the machine that I run Fiddler on has a dynamic IP. With this solution, I could ensure that the FiddlerScript seamlessly handled the changing of the IP... unfortunately I forgot that I had to run the `listen` command every time the socket changed.